# Authenticating to ASP.NET MVC site using Windows Phone WebClient and Microsoft Account (OAuth)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-phone-7, oauth, windows-live-id

I have a standard ASP.NET MVC 4 site which uses the built-in OAuthWebSecurity to allow people to login with their Microsoft Accounts (LiveId). The site and the login works OK. The site contains a **controller which requires authentication and returns JSON**. This also works OK.

I now need to be able to **access this same controller using a WebClient from a Windows Phone** app. I'm currently trying to implement this with the following method:

**1.Retrieve the authentication token** using the Live SDK:

```
var login = await authClient.LoginAsync(reqs);

var authToken = login.Session.AuthenticationToken;
```

**2.Use the authentication token to perform login** with the ASP.NET MVC site using WebClient.

```
?
```

And this is where I'm stuck. I haven't been able to figure out how could I do the login using an existing authentication token. Any ideas?

I think this should be doable, as the Azure Mobile Services uses a similar method. The Azure Mobile Service provides an option to authenticate with an existing token, so for example this works:

```
        var authClient = new LiveAuthClient("myclientid");
        ...

        var login = await authClient.LoginAsync(reqs);
        ...
        var user = await mobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(login.Session.AuthenticationToken);
```

Or am I approaching this from a wrong angle?